# localStorage persisting with looped Vue component

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm having the strangest time getting localStorage to work on my local machine. I seem to be losing indexes in the array I built, I've been trying for hours to figure out why with absolutely no luck. I've even tried different ways of building the array.

Here is the component I am loading with a v-for loop. this is working as expected.

home.vue

```
 <tweets
    v-for="tweet in tweets"
    v-bind:key="tweet.id"
    v-bind:tweet="tweet"
  ></tweets>
```

And here is the trouble-maker component. It loads a number of tweets that can be voted on. (Feel free to ignore the HTML, I'm not sure it's relevant.)

tweets.vue

```
<template>
     <div class="col-2 d-flex">
       <div class="align-self-center ml-3">
         <div class="row py-1">
           <i
             class="fas fa-arrow-up"
             style="font-size: 30px"
             v-on:click="voteUp"
           ></i>
         </div>

         <div class="row py-1">
           <i class="fas fa-arrow-down" style="font-size: 30px"></i>
         </div>
       </div>
</div>
 
</template>

<script>
export default {
data: function () {
 return {
   localStorage: [],
 };
},

props: {
 tweet: Object,
},

created: function () {
this.localStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.storageData);
console.log(this.localStorage);
},

methods: {
 voteUp: function () {
   axios
     .get("/api/vote/2/1")
     .then(({ data }) => {

         var test = {
             "tweet_id": 1,
             "vote_status": 1
         };

         this.localStorage.push(test);
         console.log(this.localStorage);
         localStorage.setItem("storageData", JSON.stringify(this.localStorage));
         console.log("go");
         //persist?


     })
     .catch(function (error) {
       alert("Take a screen shot and send this to me." + error);
       console.log(error);
     });
 },

 
},
};
</script>
```

So if you take a look at my localStorage variable, I have it being set to the current localStorage found in the browser, however...it's having this strange problem where if I click on the button that triggers the voteUp function, it will sometimes delete some of the indexes in the array. I'm having trouble explaining so I've make a quick video to demonstrate.

https://streamable.com/kkhnrx

as you can see, I'm firing the event and the array starts growing, but as I scroll down to different buttons (remember the tweets are looped) the array will lose a few of it's indexes. I have no idea why this is happening. I assume it has something to do with the component being looped and scope problems?

Comment: The example is too big to embrace, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks exactly like race condition. There are multiple component instances that compete over the storage, and it becomes overwritten eventually.

This makes an early copy that won't contain updates from other instances:

```
this.localStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.storageData)
```

`this.localStorage` should be assigned immediately before updating the storage, or there should be a common state for all component instances (e.g. by using Vuex with persistence).

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your created function, right?

If you want to get "storageData" from local storage it should be:

```
created: function () {
this.localStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('storageData'));
console.log(this.localStorage);
},
```